# Align item center and right

Tags: css

I need to align the title in the center and the buttons to the right. Sometimes there is one or two buttons (they are hidden using display none).

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0udyy325/)

```
<div>
    <h1>
        title
    </h1>
    <button>
        button 1
    </button>
    <button>
        button 2
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: C'mon it's almost 700 questions. You should know by now what a question should contain...

Comment: You forgot to actually ask a question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Basically, you'd need to use absolute positioning to take the buttons (I've wrapped them here for simplicity) out of the flow so the title can center.

```css
.parent {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
}
button {
  display: inline-block;
}
.wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <h1>
title
</h1>
  <div class="wrap">
    <button>
      button 1
    </button>
    <button>
      button 2
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```